# Как сделать из rectangle кнопку?

Tags: java, android, libgdx, mobile-development

Делаю игру точки, есть rectangle dot(сама точка), хочу сделать, что бы при нажатии на ту или иную кнопку, dot меня свой цвет на красный/синий, но когда пытаюсь ввести Gdx.input.isTouched(dot); Пишет, что isTouched не работает с rectangl'aми, как это можно реализовать по-другому? Пишу на java(libgdx) приложение для android. 
попытался сделать так:

```
public void render () {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(255, 255, 255, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    batch.begin();
    if (Gdx.input.isTouched())
        touchPos.set(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY());
        if (touchPos.x>=100 && touchPos.x <=140 && touchPos.y >= 1080-140 && touchPos.y <= 1080-100) {
            batch.draw(dotimg, dot.x, dot.y);
        }
    batch.end();
}
```

Точка рисуется, но после того, как я убрал палец с экрана - она исчезает. Как это исправить, и нет ли получше способа взаимодействия пальца(касания) с Dot? типа встроенной в Dot кнопки и тд?

Comment: Т.е. при нажатии на некую точку она должна менять цвет с красного на синий и наоборот. Так?

Comment: ну да, ну в приложенном коде я проверял просто взаимдойствие. вообщем, я разобрался, почему-то система координат для DOT начинается слева снизу, а для touchPos Слева сверху, поэтому придется писать touchPos.y <= 1080-100 && >=1080-140. НО может как-нибудь можно полегче сделать взаимодействие пальца(касания) с точкой? а не через тачпозиции? Тут главное не смена цвета, а взаимодействие с точками, более простое, чем у меня в коде. И еще одно:почему после того, как я отвожу палец от экрана точка исчезает? то есть batch.draw рисует точку, только когда палец на экране, как это исправить?

Comment: Чтобы не проверять координаты прикосновения самостоятельно нужно все это делать через Stage. Актерами будут точки. И каждому актеру следует передать ClickListener для отслеживания прикосновения. А точка исчезает потому, что batch.draw(dotimg, dot.x, dot.y) находится под условием.

Comment: а если точка уже принадлежит ректанглу, я могу ее сделать актером? или мне нужно будет создавать dotstage для этого? И еще, так если я из условия вынесу бач дроу, то он будет всегда работать, а мне нужно, чтобы он заработал только при касании, То есть поставил img и все

Comment: Актер уже содержит переменные для хранения позиции, ширины и высоты, так что Rectangle не нужен. А вообще посмотрите уроки по работе со Stage и Actor там все просто.

Comment: хорошо, спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 1):

Ну во-первых про касания. Не понял правда Rectangle dot - это "точка" в буквальном смысле, или это всё-таки прямоугольник какой-то ширины и длины? Если прямоугольник, то у Rectangle есть замечательный метод contains булевого типа. И тогда не нужно вообще заморачиваться с координатами.

Во-вторых, если не хотите использовать Actor'ов, как вам советовал Master Flomaster, то используйте флаги. Что-то типа:

```
boolean dotIsRed = false;
...
    if (dot.contains(touchPos)) { // либо if (dot.contains(touchPos.x, touchPos.y))
        if (dotIsRed) {делаем синим; dotIsRed = false}
        else {делаем красным; dotIsRed = true}
    }
```

НО! Есть одно но. Вы столкнётесь с проблемой, что при нажатии даже на пол секунды, у вас сменится цвет раз 50, т.к. проверка нажатия циклична. Нужно вручную ограничить проверку нажатия ПОСЛЕ нажатия. Допустим на одну секунду. Хотя проще использовать актёров.

Answer (score 0):

Лучше всего сделайте вашу точку объектом, чтобы в дальшейшем можно было бы менять её координаты и вечно рисовать, даже после того как вы отпустили палец.

```
if(Gdx.input.justTouched()){
Vector3 tmp=new Vector3(Gdx.input.getX(),Gdx.input.getY(),0);
cam.unproject(tmp);
dot.setPos(tmp.x, tmp.y);
//Тут можно проверить координаты и вызвать changeTexture()
}
```

Объект `Dot`:

```
    public class Dot {
        private Texture texture;
        private Vector2 pos;
        private Random rand;

    public Dot(float x, float y){
        texture = new Texture("dotImg.png");
        pos = new Vector2(x, y);
    }

    public void setPos(float x, float y){
        pos.x=x;
        pos.y=y;
    }

    public Vector2 getPos(){
        return pos;
    }

    public Texture getTexture(){
        return texture;
    }

//смена текстуры точки
    public void changeTexture(int num){
        switch(num){
        case 0: 
        texture=new Texture("dotRed.png");
        break;
        case 1: 
        texture=new Texture("dotBlue.png");
        break;
        }
    }

    }
```

И при рендере рисовать точку на своем месте:

```
batch.draw(dot.getTexture(), dot.getPos().x, dot.getPos().y);
```